# How can I change the Alt+7 shortcut in microsoft edge?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-edge

I sometimes like to use these quotation marks: „“ Since my keyboard does not have these (the standard quotation marks are "), I enter them using their unicode code. When I do this in my browser (Microsoft edge), for „ this works fine as I can just enter <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> on my numpad. For the “ character however, the code would be <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>7</kbd>. When I do this in edge, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> goes to the "new tab" page and the site that I was on before is closed.

How can I change this behaviour?

Comment: is your Windows' language in English? I am unable to reproduce Alt+7 to open the new tab (Ctrl+T opens a new page). Alt+0147 works without any issue.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio yes, my Windows is set to English (United States). However, I installed a German version, so this could perhaps make a difference.

Comment: On the German page of Edge shortcuts, Alt+Pos1 opens the home page in the current tab. I don't know if the Pos1 button and 7 are related or close as I don't speak German.

Comment: I don't know if I could post it as an answer, it is not specifically to Microsoft edge, but you can change your hotkeys with [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/). I found it worth learning.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio There is a dedicated Pos1 button on my keyboard but I just noticed that the 7 key on the numpad also is labelled Pos1. This seems to answer my question, so I encourage you to post it as one!

Comment: So Pos1 is the home key. Are you not by mistake pressing it instead of 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the English version [Keyboard shortcuts in Microsoft Edge](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-edge-50d3edab-30d9-c7e4-21ce-37fe2713cfad) does not mentioned <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> as a shortcut. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> opens a new tab and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> opens the home page on the current tab. Checking the [German version](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/microsoft-edge/tastenkombinationen-in-microsoft-edge-50d3edab-30d9-c7e4-21ce-37fe2713cfad) (thanks to translation of the page), shows that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Pos1</kbd> is the equivalent of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>.

As both <kbd>Pos1</kbd> and <kbd>7</kbd> are on the same on your keyboard, it is probable that by mistake (maybe pausing too long while typing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>) you are enabling Pos1 instead of 7; thus going to the new home page.